# Does the Hexblade warlock's Hex Warrior feature let me add my Cha bonus to attack/damage rolls with a two-handed pact weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, weapons, warlock, hexblade

The Hexblade warlock's Hex Warrior feature says (emphasis mine):

> Whenever you finish a long rest, you can touch one weapon that you are proficient with and that lacks the two-handed property. When you attack with that weapon, you can use your Charisma modifier, instead of Strength or Dexterity, for the attack and damage rolls. [...] If you later gain the Pact of the Blade feature, this benefit extends to **every** pact weapon you conjure with that feature, no matter the weapon's **type**.

Does this allow me to use my Charisma with 2-handed weapons (provided it is my pact weapon and my Hex Warrior weapon)?

---

This question is not the same as [Do the Hexblade warlock's Hex Warrior feature and the warlock's Pact of the Blade feature refer to 2 different weapons, or the same weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111371/are-the-hex-warrior-weapon-pact-of-blade-weapon-the-same-or-different). That one is asking how many weapons; I'm asking if the term "type" means two-handed weapons, or something else (e.g. slashing or ranged weapons).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes. If you can summon it as your pact of the blade weapon, it counts.

> *Emmet Byrne* @Emmetation
>   Hello @JeremyECrawford! Does this line from the Hexblade mean that if you have Pact of the Blade you can use the Hex Warrior feature with a two-handed weapon and get your Cha mod to attack and damage rolls? Thanks!
>
> *Jeremy Crawford* @JeremyECrawford
>   When we wrote "every pact weapon" in Hex Warrior, we really meant every pact weapon. #DnD

[link](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/11/17/does-this-mean-that-if-you-have-pact-of-the-blade-you-can-use-the-hex-warrior-feature-with-a-two-handed-weapon/)

Comment: Note that [Crawford's tweets are not considered official rulings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/140221/33569). You may want to edit your answer to support it by citing the rules or other evidence (e.g. clarifying what the quoted rules mean).

Comment: Note also that the sageadvice website is not affiliated in any way with Wizards of the Coast or the game designers. It is run by a third party that just compiles tweets and may be unreliable.

Answer (score 17):

#### Yes

##### And the meaning of *type* has no bearing on the answer

The rules state that:

> ...this benefit extends to *every pact weapon* you conjure with that feature, *no matter the weapon's type*.

(Emphasis mine)

'Every pact weapon you generate' is completely exhaustive: it refers to every weapon that meets the criteria of:

- Being a pact weapon
- Having been generated by you

'No matter the weapon's type' imposes no further constraint on the above. Rather, it explicitly emphasises that the above constraints are the sole constraints. 'Type' could mean any of:

- melee/ranged
- simple/martial/special
- One handed/two-handed
- Made of jelly/not made of jelly

And the meaning of the sentence would still be that you can add your CHA to any attack/damage rolls made by any pact weapon that you have generated.

Comment: Solid answer and for a little more ammo, I might also note the limitation in the Hex Warrior feature has nothing to do with damage type.  So interpreting, "...no matter the weapon's type.", as shorthand for the damage type property, would be a call back to an initial condition that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 10):

### Yes, you can use two handed pact weapon with CHA modifier

"Type" refers to a single entry in the Weapons table such as Sickle or Maul.

Interestingly enough, the Player's Handbook never refers to weapon types as it does for tools or armor. For armor *PHB p144* explicitly states:

> The **Armor table** collects the most commonly available **types of armor** found in the game (...)

The fact that "weapon types" are analogous to entries in the weapon table is demonstrated by the Kensei Weapons entry in *XGtE p34*:

> ***Kensei Weapons.*** Chose two **types of weapons** to be your kensei weapons: one melee weapon and one ranged weapon. Each of these weapons can be any simple or martial weapon that lacks the heavy and special properties. **The longbow** is also a valid choice.

This means that the benefits of the Hex Warrior feature also extend to e.g. Greatclub, Glaive or Pike that you conjure with the Pact of the Blade feature.