# Do Hexblade warlocks with Pact of the Blade ignore the limits on the type of weapons summoned?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, warlock, hexblade

I play Hexblade warlocks a lot. I, of course, usually take Pact of the Blade to go with it. It says you can only summon melee weapons. Do Hexblades ignore this rule? Would I be able to summon a longbow as as my pact weapon with Pact of the Blade?

Comment: Why do you think hexblades should or should ignore this rule? Including what specifically confused you lets us help you better, by actually addressing the problem you face. Otherwise this reads like a "read the book to me" question, which aren't very popular.

Answer (score 24):

## No, but there are ways to get a longbow

Hexblade warlocks do not get to simply ignore this rule, as nothing in their description says they can. However, the Eldritch Invocation Improved Pact Weapon includes this:

> Finally, the weapon you conjure can be a shortbow, longbow, light crossbow, or heavy crossbow.

So, even though simply being a Hexblade Warlock does not allow this, this Eldritch Invocation does

There is also a way other than that though. The pact of the blade includes:

> You can transform one magic weapon into your pact weapon by performing a special ritual while you hold the weapon

So, if you can find a magical longbow, you can make it into your pact weapon, even without the improved pact weapon invocation

Comment: It might also be worth pointing out that the Hex Warrior feature lets you "channel your will through a particular weapon", using your Charisma mod for attack and damage rolls; this benefit also extends to all weapons conjured with Pact of the Blade. This feature has different restrictions than the Pact of the Blade feature (though two-handed weapons are not allowed); is it possible OP's getting the ability to designate a weapon this way with making it your pact weapon?

Comment: Related: [Are the Hex Warrior weapon & Pact of Blade weapon the same or different?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111371/are-the-hex-warrior-weapon-pact-of-blade-weapon-the-same-or-different)